# Google Places API to find the nearby places

Tags: maps

I am trying with the Google API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.9566949,77.5606206&radius=500&types=parking&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

But response I got is like this:

```
{
    "error_message": "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I have enabled Google Places API and Maps Embed API in the dashboard. And this is not for Android or IOS. I want to make this API call from the backend.

I have gone through some of the answers like to enable **"Google Places API Web Service"** in the dashboard. But currently this option is not available.

And some people told to disable the places API and enable it again to make it work. Still it did not help me.